# Django app deployed on elastic beanstalk with MySQL RDS - tables never get created

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mysql-python, amazon-rds

I have followed every guide, and tutorial, on setting up RDS MySQL for my Django app. Everything works fine locally. When I deploy, I get no errors. My website runs. But when I try to access the restful framework I have setup, or I try to log into the admin page, I get a ProgrammingError that the table doesn't exist (none of the tables exist).

Access to the database doesn't seem to be the problem, all of my RDS environment variables are set up, the security group is set up, etc. I can even access the database from my local mysql client and I can see that the database has no tables in it.

I have commands set up in my config file to run 'django-admin.py makemigrations' and 'django-admin.py migrate', I even tried changing this to 'python manage.py ...' etc., it seems like the commands never work.

When I ssh into my elastic beanstalk environment, I can get into the mysql using 'mysql -u my_username'. However, if I navigate to the folder where my app is, and try to run 'python manage.py makemigrations' manually, I get this: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Here is my config...

requirements.txt

```
virtualenv==15.0.1
Django==1.9.5
django-compressor==2.0
django-model-utils==2.4
djangorestframework==3.3.2
dj-database-url==0.4.0
gunicorn==19.4.5
MySQL-python==1.2.5
jsonfield==1.0.3
```

.ebextentions/01_packages.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    gcc: []
    mysql: []
    mysql-devel: []
    python-devel: []
```

.ebextentions/project.config

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What is `os.environ['RDS_USERNAME']` and `os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME']` like? Can you post dummy values? Like if your `rds_username` is 'jhon' post 'doe' if it is 'jhon@localhost' post 'doe@localhost'?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir the RDS environment variables are like 'mansoorsiddiqui' for username etc. they do not contain '@Localhost' in them. Hostname is just the URL provided by the RDS endpoint. I can connect using these values on MySQL workbench too.

Comment: ` "Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"` is what makes me wonder. If it has been ` "Access denied for user 'my_username'@'IP OF APPLICATION SERVER' (using password: YES)"` then it would have meant that you need to add username@yourappserverip to MySQL users.

Comment: Maybe you can still get rid of the error by adding username@localhost in your MySQL users.

Answer (score 0):

See if the RDS security group is configured in EC2 security groups for your elastic beanstalk. It should look like this:

**EC2 security groups**: your-rds-security-group-name, your-Elastic-Beanstalk-Security-Group

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that the same settings are used when migrating and running!**

I had a similar problem but I figured out that I used local settings (from **manage.py**) when migrating. But for running i used production settings (defined in **wsgi.py**). That meant that a local database was migrated but a production one was used but was **never migrated**, thus tables were never created even if migration command returning a success. I had to change my ***django.config***:

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations"
    leader_only: true

  02_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

to:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: fund.productionSettings
```

as recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).